# Tracking changes in a cell in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a cell with 3 different columns. The first is a simple ranking, the second is a code composed by X elements and the third is a code composed by Y elements that usually is the same for a certain combination of numbers in column two. So if in column two you have the number 345, it is likely that in column three you will always have 798. The thing is that sometimes it changes. So what I have, for instance, is:

```
1 453 4789

1 56 229

1 453 1246 %here the corresponding code has changed

2 43 31

2 453 1246 %here the code did not change

3 56 31 %here the corresponding code has changed (it was 229 previously)
```

What I want to have at the end is a new cell with three columns, only descriminating the cases in which a change in the code of the third column (correspondent to the code form the second column) was observed. For instance, in this simple example I would get:

```
1 453 1246

3 56 31
```

Comment: Do all three columns of the cell have teh same length? Can we assume a 3-column matrix instead of a cell?

Comment: No! They have different lenghts.But still I can change them to a 3 column matrix if necessary!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your data in a matrix `A` you can use sorting:

```
[~, I] = sort(A(:,2));
B = A(I,:);

code_diff = logical(diff(B(:, 2)));
value_diff = logical(diff(B(:, 3)));
value_diff(code_diff) = false;

rows = sort(I([false; value_diff]));
ans = A(rows, :);
```

If the "codes" in the second column are all smallish integers, another possibility is to use a lookup table:

```
n = size(A, 1);
m = max(A(:, 2));

mask = false(n, 1);
lookup = inf(m, 1);

for i = 1:n
    code = A(i,2);
    if isinf(lookup(code))
        lookup(code) = A(i,3);
    elseif lookup(code) ~= A(i,3)
        mask(i) = true;
        lookup(code) = A(i,3);
    end
end

ans = A(mask, :);
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your help. I am now trying the first code you suggested. However the codes in the second column are indeed smallish integers so maybe the second code will also work! I will let you know. Thanks :)

Comment: No problem! I edited the code in the second block to use a slightly different strategy and it should be faster now for your array size. But try it on your actual data.

Comment: It worked perfectly and really fast (The first code). Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hello! I am trying to run a code with a very similar goal, with the difference that for the second and third column I have words/sentences, instead of numbers.So it gives me erros saying e.g. functions don't support the class'cell'. If I change the variable from str2double then instead of words I get 'NaN' so I cannot solve my problem. Do you know how can I solve this? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: I mean, instead of having a double matrix I have a cell array!

Comment: @user3557054 Now you have strings, that's different. It's better if you ask a new question.

Comment: I will do it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are in a matrix, this is a possible solution:

```
CJ2 = [1 453 4789
     1 56  229
     1 453 1246
     2 43  31
     2 453 1246
     3 56  31];

changes = zeros(size(CJ2));
nChanges = 0;
for i = 2:size(CJ2,1)
    pos = find(CJ2(1:i-1,2) == CJ2(i,2), 1, 'last');
    if ~isempty(pos) && CJ2(pos,3) ~= CJ2(i,3)
        nChanges = nChanges + 1;
        changes(nChanges, :) = CJ2(i,:);
    end
end
changes = changes(1:nChanges, :);

changes
```

Results:

```
>> changes

changes = 

       1         453        1246
       3          56          31
```

Comment: I tried your code. It gives the error: 'Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.' Do you have any idea what am I doing wrong? I really apreciate your help!

Comment: What's the output of `whos VAR`, replacing `VAR` by the name of your data cell array?

Comment: Name            Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

  CJ2       2639516x3             63348384  double

Comment: ok sorry, this may not be clear, I can try to copy paste it in a better way. I also tried in a cell form, but then the result of changes is equal to zero!

Comment: Your data is a double matrix, but I thought it was a cell array. I've edited my answer, try it now.

Comment: I see your matrix is quite big. I'll provide a faster version in just a minute. :)

Comment: No need, it's quite clear now. And I've updated my answer with a faster code, that uses preallocation on the `changes` matrix. Please try it to see if it works as you expected. Oh, and I also used the real name of you matrix. :)

Comment: OK. Thank you. The matlab is busy now. :) I will let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: Do you think it is normal that the function is running for 2 hours? I am worried something is wrong! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Well.. I think my answer is far from optimal. I suggest you take a look at the other answer, by @moarningsun. His solutions seem to be very fast. :)

Comment: Do you think it would be possible for you to repost the code that you first posted that was for a cell array instead of a double matrix? Thank you very much!

Comment: Below the answer there is a link named "[edited Apr 27 at 17:05](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23325825/revisions)" where you can find the code.

Comment: I tried your previous code and it gives me the following error:    Error using  == 
Matrix dimensions must agree. Do you know why? Thanks

Comment: It means the "==" operator is comparing two matrices which are not of the same size. Try typing **whos** on Matlab to see the variables size and check what is wrong.

Comment: But that's strange since I am only dealing with one Matrix.